# React not running in android

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to run my react project for my android phone . But when typing this command `react-native run-android`

This error appears:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
* Try:
```

Run with `--stacktrace option` to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug option` to get more log output.

```
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Any help please.

Comment: Have you referred to the links and other content in the error log?

Comment: Which operating system  are you trying to run the project on ?

Comment: It may be a problem with permission of the android folder, if it is linux or mac system then give full permission to the android folder

Answer (score 1):

It literally means what it says, you don't have an emulator running or a device configured in debug/development mode connected to your computer.

run the following (assuming you have the android tools setup correctly, look here for instructions on how to do this: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)

```
adb devices
```

if you get the following:

```
List of devices attached
```

If there's nothing listed then you either need to start an emulator using Android Studio, command line or something like https://www.genymotion.com/.

if you're trying to connect to your Android device via USB then you need to check the version of Android you are using and enable development mode via USB in your device's settings.

here's some docs on how to enable your device for development: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options

Once you have an emulator or device configured and attached you can run:

```
adb devices
```

If everything is working correctly you should see a list of device(s) available.

```
react-native run-android
```

Should now work as expected.